# How to insert value in empty data frame in spark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am developing a spark application using SPARK sql, one of my job is selecting value from two tables and insert it into an empty table which is my result. but for this i am experimenting with spark for creating a empty table ,i have created a empty data frame but cant  register it as table  here is my situation now the code

```
from pyspark import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField,StringType,DateType,IntegerType
sqlc=SQLContext(sc)

schema= StructType([StructField("Name",StringType(),False),StructField("AGE",IntegerType(),False),StructField("DATE",DateType(),False)])

dataframe=sqlc.createDataFrame([],schema)
dataframe.show()
```

it is showing a dataframe  but  i am not sure whether it is register or not cause the there is no value

```
dataframe.registerTempTable("Exp")
experiment=sqlc.sql("SELECT * FROM Exp")
experiment.show()
```

I think i am making mistake here , so for this issue  i want to insert some value  for testing but i am unable to do it. i am new in spark so not sure how could i solve this situation . i have gone through some forums i have seen some forum user mentioned about parallelize() method for creating table but i did not properly understand how it works.Is it mandatory to use hive context for operation purpose?  my requirements are doing this job without hive context . Please guide me

Comment: Why is Hadoop mentioned in the tags? Correct me if I am wrong, but the question doesn't seem to mention Hadoop at all?

Comment: oops sorry that was in suggestion  i did not remove it by mistake  thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: you don't.

Spark dataframes are built on top of RDD, which are *immutable*. This is a bit hard to get used to in the beginning, but you can work with it.

You can create a brand new DataFrame by running some transformations on an existing one (e.g. using SQL statements in your spark-sql), by reading some input data or by entering the data manually with *sqlContext.createDataFrame(...)*.

Is there any particular reason why you can't just create a new DataFrame with your result and register it as table if you need to?

**edit:** I'm not sure if I understood your question well... maybe the thing I'm proposing is exactly what you want to do. In that case:

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([("val1","val2","val1")], ["colName1", "colName2", "colName3"])
```

Comment: thanks your reply my scenario is  i am getting data from a remote database and load it on spark and create registerTempTable, i am doing operation on that. i have two temp table which i will union then insert the result on a new fresh empty table . i have created a empty data frame and table but could not insert it .

Comment: grepe  i have tried your above code it works . by this i have created data frame with  empty value like this  (" "," ","") and also created a temp table .  and here I tried  to insert some values by using SQL query like sqlcontext.sql( INSERT INTO TABLE(Column name) VALUES("values")) but i was unsuccessful . is it possible querying like this .sorry for bothering you again :)

Comment: @Kalyan as I wrote before, once DF is created, it's set in stone. you can't change it and thus you can't do things like SQL update or insert with it. you must create *new* data frame every time you change something. when you want one with data from your old DF and some new entries, you make DF with new records and use (union)[http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.union] to create a DF with data from both. when you run SQL-like statement, result is already a new DF. perhaps you want to use something like Hive instead of spark if you need inserts?

Answer (score 0):

> parallelize() method for creating table but i did not properly understand how it works.

Simply put - the parallize method takes a sequence of input, and creates input splits from it.

> for this issue i want to insert some value for testing

You either need to parallize a list of Dataframe Row objects or create a file, and map a SQL schema over that

> my job is selecting value from two tables

Then start there. Write a SELECT statement against two tables, it returns a new table, which you register and can write out to the database / disk

Comment: thanks for  your reply , i have seen in databricks about parallelize() method but it also said i have to use savedasTable() instead of registerTempTable() but i have understand so far that  savedasTable() we can use if there is Hivecontext or Hive meta table. there this term is confusing me . any way thanks i will try your idea :)

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. You can use the Dataframe API without a HiveContext. But you must use the HiveContext if the data is loaded into Hive.

Comment: i am just using spark standalone. and not loading data in hive  so you are saying if my data is loaded in hive  then i have to use hivecontext Right. but somewhere i have read  that  if i want to save the table permanently i need to work with hivecontext that confused me.  sorry for bothering you my concept was unclear but i have got some idea